# HTML objects growing and pushing others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How could I make it so that given two elements let's say these boxes: 
[image]

If I clicked over one, it would grow, and the other would shrink like and vice versa: 
[image]

How can I do this?

I have seen this sort of done with CSS, using the focus tag and adjusting the width. But I have two problems there, first how could I affect the other element, and second as far as I can tell adjusting width will only stretch them right. I have seen people change the way they float the elements to deal with that, but I don't want to move them around the page to do this.

Comment: You mean something like this: http://devsmash.com/projects/kwicks/2.2.x/examples/horizontal ? You can configure it to be onclick instead of hover.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer that is exactly what I am looking for thank you, go ahead and move your comment to the answer.

Comment: Well this isnt really an answer, just a hint. ;)

Comment: How hard can it be -> http://jsfiddle.net/6Gndb/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are 2 examples **without Javascript/jQuery:**

### Pure CSS - Trigger on click: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/cMqyD/)

Using the checkbox hack in CSS you can effectively toggle the widths of the elements when the checkbox is `:checked`. Here is what part of the CSS looks like:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .red {
    width:70%;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .green {
    width:20%;
}
```

Go to the [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/cMqyD/) for the full CSS.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
<div class="red">
    <label for="toggle"></label>
</div>
<div class="green">
    <label for="toggle"></label>
</div>
```

<sub>You might also be interested in the original [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/8362D/) I made. It takes a different approach, though it doesn't fully work.</sub>

### Pure CSS - Trigger on hover: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/3j77F/)

Unfortunately, neither the adjacent selector, nor the general sibling selector can select previous elements, therefore it makes this a little difficult. I placed 2 general elements before the main elements in order to somewhat solve this issue.

```
.greenS:hover, .greenS:hover ~ .green,
.redS:hover, .redS:hover ~ .red {
    width:72%;
}
.greenS:hover ~ .redS, .greenS:hover ~ .red,
.redS:hover ~ .greenS, .redS:hover ~ .green {
    width:22%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="redS"></div><div class="greenS"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

---

Since this was tagged as JS/jQuery, here are 2 alternative solutions.

### JS/jQuery - Trigger on click: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/eamzY/)

```
$('.red, .green').click(function(){
    $('.red').toggleClass('expanded')
    .next('.green').toggleClass('contracted');
});
```

### JS/jQuery - Trigger on hover: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/H5J4e/)

```
$('.red').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded')
    .next('.green').toggleClass('contracted');
});
$('.green').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded')
    .prev('.red').toggleClass('contracted');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See [jQuery .animate() method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) documentation.

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5u564/):

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#box1 {
    background: red;
}

#box2 {
    background: blue;
}
```

```
<div class="box" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box2"></div>
```

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    var currentWidth = $(this).outerWidth(),
        siblingCurrentWidth = $(this).siblings('.box').outerWidth();

    $(this).animate({'width' : currentWidth/2})
    .siblings('.box').animate({'width' : siblingCurrentWidth*2});
});
```

This is a very simple example with several flaws, but it demonstrates a possibility for what your purpose is.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example http://jsfiddle.net/PeLub/ ( modify how you need) .

```
<div class="box" id="first"></div>
<div class="box" id="second"></div>

 $("#first").click(function(){
  $(this).animate({width:'50px'}, 500);
  $("#second").animate({width:'150px'}, 500);    
 });

 $("#second").click(function(){
  $(this).animate({width:'50px'}, 500);
  $("#first").animate({width:'150px'}, 500);    
 });
```